# Sierra Wireless GSM modem EM7455 + Android Integration Error

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, arch-linux, gsm

EM7455 connect on Single Board Computer(NanoPC-T2) through USB.

I have attached AndroidRIL_5.1.11 binary files in my android and kernel source after build it and run on my android device.Below error messages received on android Log:

```
# dmesg | grep sierra                                           
<6>[    1.184000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra_net

<6>[   40.552000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra

<6>[   40.564000] sierra: v.1.7.42_android_generic_2:USB Driver for Sierra Wireless USB modems

<3>[   47.308000] sierra_net: module is already loaded

<6>[   87.844000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: Sierra USB modem converter detected

<4>[   87.872000] sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs 
usb_get_serial_port_data(port_tmp) = 0xd8c90000


<4>[   87.880000] kfree at sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs

<6>[   87.884000] sierra ttyUSB0: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0

<6>[   87.892000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: device disconnected

<6>[   90.920000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: Sierra USB modem converter detected
<4>[   90.948000] sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs 
usb_get_serial_port_data(port_tmp) = 0xda6b8d80

<4>[   90.956000] kfree at sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs

<6>[   90.960000] sierra ttyUSB0: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0

<6>[   90.968000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: device disconnected


127|root@nanopi2:/ # dmesg | grep sierra                                       
<6>[    1.184000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra_net
<6>[   40.552000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra
<6>[   40.564000] sierra: v.1.7.42_android_generic_2:USB Driver for Sierra Wireless USB modems

<3>[   47.308000] sierra_net: module is already loaded
<6>[   87.844000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: Sierra USB modem converter detected
<4>[   87.872000] sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs usb_get_serial_port_data(port_tmp) = 0xd8c90000

<4>[   87.880000] kfree at sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs

<6>[   87.884000] sierra ttyUSB0: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0

<6>[   87.892000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: device disconnected

<6>[   90.920000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: Sierra USB modem converter detected

<4>[   90.948000] sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs 

usb_get_serial_port_data(port_tmp) = 0xda6b8d80
<4>[   90.956000] kfree at sierra_remove_sysfs_attrs
<6>[   90.960000] sierra ttyUSB0: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0

<6>[   90.968000] sierra 1-1.1:1.0: device disconnected
```

Anyone known how to solve this error,help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not positive but this may be a bug that was fixed with [a patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/usb/cdc_ncm.c?id=c086e7096170390594c425114d98172bc9aceb8a) that was added to the Linux Kernel.

Also make sure you have the Sierra Wireless Serial USB, Sierra Wireless WWAN, and Qualcomm QMI drivers built into your kernel.

Comment: Thanks Liam. I am added Linux kernel file and sierra framework file in my android source code.Sierra wireless modem successfully worked.